# WSO2 Identity Server (IS) 6.0 startup delay and token endpoint errors

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are trying to setup WSO2 Identity Server 6.0 and we see the startup time is more in comparison to WSO2IS 5.10.

When we look into the log we see the below set of errors logged heavily while starting the apps under /repository/deployment/server/webapps.Despite these errors Management console starts up as expected with a delay of minimum 15 min and we are able to do the configuration.

We are using Linux OS (Debain 11) and Open jdk 11.

==========================================================================

TID: [] [] [2022-09-28 14:00:52,109] []  WARN {org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader} - Ignored XML validation warning org.xml.sax.**SAXParseException**; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 242; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not xsd:schema.

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: **Connection timed out** (Connection timed out)

TID: [] [] [2022-09-28 14:00:52,128] [] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/mexut]} - Servlet.init() for servlet [MexEndpoints] threw exception org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 23 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.**SAXParseException**; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 242; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

TID: [] [] [2022-09-28 20:49:57,408] [] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/wso2]} - Servlet [SCIMServlet] in web application [/wso2] threw load() exception org.xml.sax.**SAXParseException**; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 242; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

==========================================================================

**These are the logs from WSO2 Identity Server v6.0 where we have added our customizations to deployment.toml w.r.t UserStore and ServiceProvider. When we try to invoke the https://wso2.local/oauth2/token endpoint from postman,we get "HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error". In the logs we see similar SAXParseException and Connection timed out errors that we see in the above instance which has no customizations.**.

TID: [-1234] [oauth2] [2022-09-29 12:16:29,637] [9ed75594-84a9-4bd8-b9fd-a3bf488343b2] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/oauth2].[OAuth2Endpoints]} - Allocate exception for servlet [OAuth2Endpoints] org.xml.sax.**SAXParseException**; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 242; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Caused by: org.xml.sax.**SAXParseException**; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 242; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: **Connection timed out** (Connection timed out)
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

TID: [-1234] [oauth2] [2022-09-29 12:16:29,609] [9ed75594-84a9-4bd8-b9fd-a3bf488343b2] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/oauth2]} - Servlet.init() for servlet [OAuth2Endpoints] threw exception org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 23 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.**SAXParseException**; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 242; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

**Can someone please point out/guide if we are missing something in the basic setup?**

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the IS-6.0.0 server without public internet connection? Seems you have faced the same issue mentioned in https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/11669. Therefore several web apps were not deployed properly. Since oauth2 web app is not properly deployed (`ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/oauth2]} - Servlet.init() for servlet [OAuth2Endpoints] threw exception`) oauth2/token request is failing.

Would you be able to try the IS-6.0.0 server startup on a server that has public internet connection?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. We tried with 
export https_proxy="<proxy_host>:proxy_port>"
to connect to internet and then we restarted wso2server 
./wso2server.sh restart.
 We are able to do a curl towards "google.com", however when we tried to do  wso2 server restart the "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException" exception persists.

We are actually looking to upgrade from WSO2 IS 5.10 to 6.0 but this doesn't seem to be so easy, what would you suggest to wait for any update from WSO2 side addressing this issue or go with 5.11 upgrade?
Your help and guidance is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: We tried with IS-6.0.0 server startup on a server that has public internet connection and it works fine. Due to Security constraints the Test environments are not connected to Internet. However, they are allowed via Proxy for a small duration of time, may be only during startup of WSo2 IS, hence we tried with export https_proxy="<proxy_host>:proxy_port>" to connect to internet and it didnt work. Is there any alternate way to configure proxy and achieve the desirable functionality? - Thanks in advance.